# Collection of properties in WMI to do inventory of databases

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, wmi

I'm putting together a PowerShell script that will create a WMI class and its instances to do an inventory of SQL server instances.  I've done this and it works when grabbing information about the instances themselves.  What I'd like the instances to contain as well are date about the actual databases.  e.g. is mirroring enabled, collation, language settings, etc.

Of course there will be multiple databases per instance. Getting the data with SMO I'm fine with.  It's WMI I'm struggling with.  Is it possible to have "nested objects" or collections within a WMI instance?  If so... how?

**Examples:**

*MyInstance.Database* would return the properties for each database in the instance.

*MyInstance.Database.Name* would return all of the database names

I'm new to WMI, but I've noticed (when using wbemtest) that there is a property database of CIM_PROPERTY.  Would this be the way forward?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: I don't think WMI has visibility into many of those settings within SQL Server, and you have to use either SMO or SQL queries for that level of detail.

Comment: Yup, I'm using SMO to populate WMI.  The reason being that SCCM is able to query WMI across our estate.  So SCCM will drop a package that will run the PS script, which in turn will populate WMI with the information gathered via SMO.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to add the database level info into WMI in the way I want, or if it's even possible.  An SMO object of the SQL Instance, for example, does what I'm talking about.  

$ServerObject = New-Object('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') 'MySQLInstance';
$ServerObject.Databases;

I was hoping to replicate that kind of structure in WMI.

Comment: Hmmm... reading up at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390351(v=vs.85).aspx.    Section titled "Relating Objects to Each Other."  May help.  But going home now.